# Query with variable in Where Clause

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have a form with a list box which I want to populate with the results of a query (as an Access Query, not in VBA). This query has a Where clause based on a primary key.  Just to get the concept down, I hard-coded the value of the PK (in the Criteria of the Query) - and that worked.  What I really need to do is make a variable so that the value will be dependent on something that happens in the app.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call a global function in the `WHERE` clause of the query.

You will write a function in VBA e.g.

```
Public Function ValueForQuery() as Long
   ValueForQuery = x 'x will be the value you want to pass from the app
End Function
```

In the query:

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE PK = ValueForQuery()
```

Comment: Thanks - I'll try that. I though there may have been a way to do entirely outside of VBA.

Comment: I'm having a little problem.  Just to make sure I understand - In the query you have above, can that be in the Criteria in the 'Access query'? That is, not embedded SQL in VBA.  Because when I do that and run, it prompts me to put in a value with a box called ' Enter Parameter Value' and the field (function) name.

Comment: Been tweaking a little bit, but the problem I have now is that the query does not seem to recognize the function.  When opening the query  I get msg: "Undefined function in 'xyz' in expression".  But maybe that makes sense when just opening the query by itself.  Could this be an indication that maybe the function isn't 'global'?

Comment: Playing around got me a little farther.  I don't think I had a truly global function.  It seemed to be associated to a form.  I found how how to create a 'standard module'.  I dummied this up to get a POC with the function idea, so I may have a follow up question.